# getting xml parse exception while reading xml tag value from xml by java

Tags: java, xml

I have the following value in the xml as shown below

```
<entry>
<key>
<value>FUTURESproduct</value>
</key>
<value>ROLFE & NOLAN</value>
</entry>
```

and now i am reading this key value in java as shown below

```
if (incomingProduct!= null &&  incomingProduct.equalsIgnoreCase("FUTURES") ) {
             brokerInvoice.setSourceSystem((String)configuration.getConfiguration().get("FUTURESproduct"));
```

now upon reading this key in java, i am getting the below exception

```
nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
```

folks please show how to escape the & special character

Comment: `&` is a special character, you need escape it.

Comment: @waltersu so can i do like this ROLFE &amp; NOLAN , please show how to escape it